# Plotting a solution and its derivative, of a first order ODE

Tags: matplotlib, odeint

I have this code to solve a simple first order ODE using odeint. I managed to plot the solution y(r), but I also want to plot the derivative y'= dy/dr. I know y' it is given by f(y,r), but I'm not sure how to call the function with the output of the integration. Thank you in advance.

```
    from math import sqrt
    from numpy import zeros,linspace,array
    from scipy.integrate import odeint
    import matplotlib.pylab as plt

    def f(y,r):
        f = zeros(1)
        f[0] = -(y[0]*(y[0]-1.0)/r)-y[0]*(2/r+\
        ((r/m)/(1-r**2/m))*(2*sqrt(1-r**2/m)-k)/(k-sqrt(1-r**2/m)))\
        -(1/(1-r**2/m))*(-l*(l+1)/r+\
         (3*r/m)*(k+2*sqrt(1-r**2/m))/(k-sqrt(1-r**2/m)))\
        +((4*r**3)/((m**2)*(1-r**2/m)))*(1/(k-sqrt(1-r**2/m))**2)
        return f

    m = 1.15            
    k = 3*sqrt(1-1/m)
    l = 2.0
    r = 1.0e-10                         
    rf = 1.0                         

    rspan = linspace(r,rf,1000)
    y0 = array([l])
    sol = odeint(f,y0,rspan)
    plt.plot(rspan,sol,'k:',lw=1.5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `odeint` [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html):

> For new code, use [scipy.integrate.solve_ivp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_ivp) to solve a differential equation.

I have modified your code in the following manner and obtained the figure below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import gradient, squeeze, sqrt
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp


def fun(t, y):
    l = 2
    m = 1.15
    k = 3 * sqrt(1 - 1 / m)
    return (-y * (y - 1) / t - y * (2 / t + t / m / (1 - t ** 2 / m)
                                    * (2 * sqrt(1 - t ** 2 / m) - k)
                                    / (k - sqrt(1 - t ** 2 / m)))
            - 1 / (1 - t ** 2 / m) * (-l * (l + 1) / t + 3 * t / m
                                      * (k + 2 * sqrt(1 - t ** 2 / m))
                                      / (k - sqrt(1 - t ** 2 / m)))
            + 4 * t ** 3 / m ** 2 / (1 - t ** 2 / m)
            / (k - sqrt(1 - t ** 2 / m)) ** 2)


sol = solve_ivp(fun, t_span=[1e-10, 1], y0=[2], method='BDF',
                dense_output=True)
if sol.success is True:
    print(sol.t.shape, sol.y.shape)
    plt.plot(sol.t, squeeze(sol.y), color='xkcd:avocado',
             label='Scipy Solution')
    plt.plot(sol.t, fun(sol.t, squeeze(sol.y)), linestyle='dashed',
             color='xkcd:purple', label='Derivative Using the Function')
    plt.plot(sol.t, gradient(squeeze(sol.y), sol.t), linestyle='dotted',
             color='xkcd:bright orange', label='Derivative Using Numpy')
    plt.legend()
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig('so.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=300)
    plt.show()
```

[image]

To address the comment about `squeeze`, please see below (extracted from [scipy.integrate.solve_ivp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_ivp)):

[image]

where `n` is defined according to:

[image]

Comment: What is `squeeze`? Why is it necessary?

Comment: Doc is here (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html). After the if condition, if you execute `print(sol.t.shape, sol.y.shape)`, you should get `(32,) (1, 32)`, which shows that t is 1D while y is 2D. Therefore, squeeze is needed.

Comment: I know... what I mean is that your answer is not complete.

Comment: I think it's correct, I checked your code with my equation again and it works. I think you missed something when you rewrote the ODE. I did not know about the squeeze, thank you!

Comment: @CamPos You are right, I had a `*` instead of a `/` in the before-last line. Would you mind accepting the answer (see here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helped you? Thank you.

Comment: @gboffi Do you mind expanding a little more? It is not clear what you are trying to say. Also, see my edit on the answer.