# How to monitor the process of SciPy.odeint?

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations, odeint

SciPy can solve ode equations by scipy.integrate.odeint or other packages, but it gives result after the function has been solved completely. However, if the ode function is very complex, the program will take a lot of time(one or two days) to give the whole result. So how can I mointor the step it solve the equations(print out result when the equation hasn't been solved completely)?

Comment: I, unfortunately, do not know the answer, if there exists one, but I agree it would be useful. In terms of speed, you might achieve faster execution time by using [solve_ivp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html): it is now the recommended function. If you are interested in trying it out and comparing the results (there are five different methods), I gave an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58854745/10640534).

Comment: have you tried setting `printmessg=True` or  `printmessg=1`? I haven't tried it myself but in the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) it mentions that this will print out a convergence message but honestly I have no idea what

Comment: @Patol75 : odeint uses the FORTRAN implementation of ODEPACK. solve_ivp is a pure python implementation using wrappers etc. to make readable and versatile code, it will not be faster. (You might find some counter-examples in comparing odeint and the Radau method of solve_ivp, as the latter one might produce larger step sizes.)

Comment: @DrBwts I have tried `printmessg` before, it doesn't give the message what I want.

Answer (score 7):

When I was googling for an answer, I couldn't find a satisfactory one. So I made a simple [gist](https://gist.github.com/thomaslima/d8e795c908f334931354da95acb97e54) with a proof-of-concept solution using the [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) project. Hope that helps you.

Edit: Moderators asked me to give an explanation of what is going on in the link above.

First of all, I am using scipy's OOP version of `odeint` (`solve_ivp`) but you could adapt it back to `odeint`. Say you want to integrate from time `T0` to `T1` and you want to show progress for every 0.1% of progress. You can modify your ode function to take two extra parameters, a `pbar` (progress bar) and a `state` (current state of integration). Like so:

```py
def fun(t, y, omega, pbar, state):
    # state is a list containing last updated time t:
    # state = [last_t, dt]
    # I used a list because its values can be carried between function
    # calls throughout the ODE integration
    last_t, dt = state
    
    # let's subdivide t_span into 1000 parts
    # call update(n) here where n = (t - last_t) / dt
    time.sleep(0.1)
    n = int((t - last_t)/dt)
    pbar.update(n)
    
    # we need this to take into account that n is a rounded number.
    state[0] = last_t + dt * n
    
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    dydt = 1j * y * omega
    return dydt
```

This is necessary because the function itself must know where it is located, but scipy's `odeint` doesn't really give this context to the function. Then, you can integrate `fun` with the following code:

```py
T0 = 0
T1 = 1
t_span = (T0, T1)
omega = 20
y0 = np.array([1], dtype=np.complex)
t_eval = np.arange(*t_span, 0.25/omega)

with tqdm(total=1000, unit="‰") as pbar:
    sol = solve_ivp(
        fun,
        t_span,
        y0,
        t_eval=t_eval,
        args=[omega, pbar, [T0, (T1-T0)/1000]],
    )
```

Note that anything mutable (like a list) in the `args` is instantiated once and can be changed from within the function. I recommend doing this rather than using a global variable.

This will show a progress bar that looks like this:

```
100%|█████████▉| 999/1000 [00:13<00:00, 71.69‰/s]
```

Comment: When you have edited your post to fix the issue(s) mentioned above, you can flag for a moderator to review & undelete.

Answer (score 2):

You could split the integration domain and integrate the segments, taking the last value of the previous as initial condition of the next segment. In-between, print out whatever you want. Use numpy.concatenate to assemble the pieces if necessary.

In a standard example of a 3-body solar system simulation, replacing the code

```py
u0 = solsys.getState0();
t = np.arange(0, 100*365.242*day, 0.5*day);
%timeit u_res = odeint(lambda u,t: solsys.getDerivs(u), u0, t, atol = 1e11*1e-8, rtol = 1e-9)
```

> output: `1 loop, best of 3: 5.53 s per loop`

with a progress-reporting code

```py
def progressive(t,N):
    nk = [ int(n+0.5) for n in np.linspace(0,len(t),N+1) ]
    u0 = solsys.getState0();
    u_seg = [ np.array([u0]) ];
    for k in range(N):
        u_seg.append( odeint(lambda u,t: solsys.getDerivs(u), u0, t[nk[k]:nk[k+1]], atol = 1e11*1e-8, rtol = 1e-9)[1:] )
        print t[nk[k]]/day
        for b in solsys.bodies: print("%10s %s"%(b.name,b.x))
    return np.concatenate(u_seg)
%timeit u_res = progressive(t,20)
```

> output: `1 loop, best of 3: 5.96 s per loop`

shows only a slight 8% overhead for console printing. With a more substantive ODE function, the fraction of the reporting overhead will reduce significantly.

---

That said, python, at least with its standard packages, is not the tool for industrial-scale number-crunching. Always use compiled versions with strong typing of variables to reduce interpretative overhead as much as possible.

- Use some heavily developed and tested package like Sundials or the julia-lang framework differentialequations.jl directly coding the ODE function in an appropriate compiled language. Use the higher-order methods for larger step sizes, thus smaller steps. Test if using implicit or exponential/Rosenbrock methods reduces the number of steps or ODE function evaluations per fixed interval further. The difference can be a factor of 10 to 100 in speedup.
- Use a python wrapper of the above with some acceleration-friendly implementation of your ODE function.
- Use the quasi-source-translating tool JITcode to translate your python ODE function to a spaghetti list of C instruction that then give a compiled function that can be (almost) directly called from the compiled FORTRAN kernel of odeint.

Comment: Your answer is quite helpful, I will try the methods your suggested. What I have used before is [GAMD](https://archimede.dm.uniba.it/~testset/testsetivpsolvers/?page_id=30) based on FORTRAN. However, it some times suddenly get "NAN", so I have to try another way. Here I want to discrib my function a little, so that you may give me some more specific answer.
    $dy_{i}/dt = Hy_{i} - y_{i}H$, both H and y is a 4*4 matrix. H=$\Sigma (a_{i}(t)y_{i})+b(t)$

Comment: t runs from 10 to 200, and the function is very unstable. If using R-K method of other 4, the initial step size should be around 10^{-7}.

Comment: If there are no conditions present that force boundedness, such a quadratic right side has very good chances to lead to a blow-up in finite times. That is, the exact solution diverges, and any good enough numerical method will follow that behavior. Did you exclude that possibility, and how?

Answer (score 0):

Simple and Clear.
If you want to integrate an ODE from T0 to T1:
In the last line of the code, before return, you can use `print((t/T1)*100,end='')`
Then use a sys.stdout.flush() to keep the same line of printing.

Here is an example. My integrating time [0 0.2]

```
ddt[-2]=(beta/(Ap2*(L-x)))*(-Qgap+Ap*u)
ddt[-1]=(beta/(Ap2*(L+x)))*(Qgap-Ap*u)
print("\rCompletion percentage "+str(format(((t/0.2)*100),".4f")),end='')
sys.stdout.flush()
return ddt
```

It slows a bit the solving process by fraction of seconds, but it serves perfectly the purpose rather than creating new functions.